# Analyzing complete games on iPad?

Tags: analysis

I have several apps on my iPad that will analyze the current position as I move through a game, but I can't seem to find any that will do an analysis of a complete game, ala the sort of analysis I used to do with Fritz when I still had a working PC. I don't need Grand Master level preparation insights (as in, I'm not trying to replicate the depth that Fritz could look at), just looking for something that will point out blunders and mistakes etc.

Comment: SmallFish will add this feature (blunder check) in the next release (when the next Stockfish version is ready). Other than that, I'm not aware of any app that can do that.

Comment: Thanks for replying -- I have SmallFish, so I'm looking forward to that. Seems oddly lacking on the iPad -- it was easy to find an app that did this on my Android phone (Analyze This combined with Android Komodo), but I'd much rather use the larger screen of my iPad.

Comment: It's a matter of motivation and nobody has stepped in to do it. Analyze This is a commercial app, while SmallFish is free.

Comment: It's interesting that Analyze This on the iPad doesn't appear to be able to perform analysis of an entire game, just the current position. The iPad version appears to be well behind the Android version. But yes, I understand about the motivation, just seems to be curious that not even the commercial apps have filled this space.

Comment: Which means, I assume, that my instinct that there is a demand for it must be wrong. Although, given that to me the iPad seems to be a reasonably major platform, the absolute basic-ness of the Chessbase apps was very surprising to me.

Comment: I know there's a demand, I've been asked to implement full-game analysis for SmallFish many times, more than I can remember. I just haven't got a chance to do it properly. The feature is not as simple as you might think. It requires to define what exactly a blunder and what annotation text to give for each bad move.

Comment: Both Chessbase and Analyze This are based on Android. Their developers are hard-coded Android users, they don't understand and don't care iOS devices.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting -- I would have thought the engine would have handled the assessments, or do you mean you have to accurately interpret the engine assessments?

Comment: The engine only gives evaluation scores, it's not a good idea just dump those scores out to you. The analysis needs to tell the user when a blunder happens and this can happen if we have a definition of a blunder. Is losing 0.5 score a blunder? What about 1.5?

Comment: Yep, understood, more complicated than I assumed.

Answer (score 2):

Smallfish as mentioned is good, the website lichess.org has made an app, you can downnload it and make an account. It needs internet connection for the database but not for the complete game analysis

Answer (score -2):

[Analyze this](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/analyze-this-chess/id1090863537?l=en&mt=8) is a chess tool for iPhone/iPad which is a good app and you can include that as well.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to it?

Comment: Please type " Analyze this Chess " on Apple App store .

Comment: Why is it a minus @Glorfindel ? kindly make me understand .

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your original answer (without the link) was really substandard; right now, it *looks* very similar to a typical spam post.